# What is the correlation between the CPU usage and Memory being used?

Tags: memory, cpu-usage, taskmanager

1) why does working set image name list and peak working set list is different under processes tab in task manager? What is the relation between working set and peak working set?
2) What is the correlation between the CPU usage and Memory being used?

And also I would like to know about the CPU and memory usage on physical and kernel memory.
For example if I open Internet explorer.
How does the internet explorer application impact on CPU usage and Memory, Physical and kernel memory?

Please help me out I am fully confused?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The *working set* is the pages that a process has in physical memory.

The *peak working set* is the largest size of the working set.

The working set can grow and shrink depending upon the competing memory demands of processes running on a system

There is little correlation between CPU usage an memory usage. It's possible for a process to have high CPU usage and low memory usage or high CPU usage and high memory usage.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Okay. If I open Internet explorer, how and why does the internet explorer application impact on CPU usage and Memory, Physical and kernel memory? I mean what is the correlation between opening internet explorer and working set, peak working set, CPU usage and memory usage, Physical and kernel memory?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you open a browser, there is a lot of setup activity both in the app and in the kernel. That causes a huge spike in CPU and possibly memory usage. Also, if you have little real memory to begin with, you can have a lot of pages moving into and out of physical memory (almost thrashing).